# Проблема с рекурсией в матлаб

Tags: память, рекурсия, matlab

Здравствуйте.

В ходе выполнения практики мне потребовалось написать DFS на matlab. DFS написал рекурсивной функцией

```
function [OK, next] = DFS(x0, y0, num, OK, yStart, yEnd) 
    global checked;
    global A;



    x = [0, 1, 0, -1];
    y = [1, 0, -1, 0];
    checked(y0, x0) = 1;
    if (~A(y0, x0))
        next = false;
        return;
    end;
    next = true;
    A(y0, x0) = num;              
    if (y0 < yStart)
        yStart = y0;
    end;
    if (y0 > yEnd)
        yEnd = y0;
    end;
    if (yEnd >= size(A, 1) && yStart <= 1)
        OK = 1;
    end;
    for i = 1 : 4
        if (y0 + y(i) >= 1 && x0 + x(i) >= 1 && y0 + y(i) <= size(A, 1) && x0 + x(i) <= size(A, 2) && ~checked(y0 + y(i), x0 + x(i)) && A(y0 + y(i), x0 + x(i)))
            [OK, next] = DFS(x0 + x(i), y0 + y(i), num, OK, yStart, yEnd);
        end;
    end;
end
```

Но при больших значениях глобальной матрицы А (400х400 +) матлаб решает вылетать без объяснения причин. Очень похоже на то, что происходит переполнение памяти. Причём, если запустить несколько раз функцию с разными размерами матрицы, то после k запусков, вылетать начинает при значениях 300x300+, а если запускать большее количество раз, то уже при 200х200+ раз. Такое ощущение, что не очищается память. Непонятно.

Пожскажите, куда смотреть.